# particular use case of centering a div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am centering a div in a case I use a css grid.

The relevant code is, in the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/nfs509rw/24/

```
  <div class="position3 horizontal-center">

 .horizontal-center {
    margin: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-25%, -0%);
    transform: translate(-25%, -0%);
  }
```

Normally, in all the use case, to center the div, I should apply

```
 .horizontal-center {
    margin: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
  }
```

Why Shall I use a value of -25% instead of -50% ?

Comment: Relevant code should here on Stack Overflow. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to get a very similar editing experience to jsfiddle.

Comment: remove the width you are setting to that element and you can use the  classic centring code

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, it does not work